# Specific backup task: Which tool?

Tags: backup

Which tool can do the following:

I have two hard drives. I want to store several TB of data on both of them. On the first one is the original data. On the second one there should be a backup of it. This can be either in the form of folders/files or another (archived, etc.).

The backup is done once, then the external disk is moved to another location.

From now on, only incremental backups are to be made. The problem: The external full Backup is not accessible anymore, but it should be done against some kind of catalog that contains the metadata of the already backed up data. I have found 4 ways so far to do something like this:

"dar" -> problem: resuming aborted backups is tedious.

"zbackup" -> with moving the bundles folder away. bad performance and the "tar" way is quite strange for me.

"storeBackup.pl" -> complicated configuration, unmaintained

"BTRFS" send / receive -> not very transparent and I don't think it's meant to do that. It should synchronize two locations, but that's not what I want to do.

Who knows another one?